# Infopath 2013 validation error message about a missing field

Tags: 2013, infopath, error, column, validation

Currently testing a Sharepoint list form customized in Infopath.

Once I've been through the whole - long- form in Sharepoint, and click on 'submit' the form returns a message error that reads:

> Warning
>
> The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values). Field or group: my:**CoI** Error: Cannot be blank
>   Click OK to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors. 
>   An error occurred while using the form. For more information, contact the site administrator.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.
>
> Log ID:5567
>
> Correlation ID:84bbac9d-903a-3000-a1e2-23725f992595

The issue is, when I check for the control '**CoI**' in Infopath Designer, I cannot find it in the list of fields, either in basic or advanced view.

How is it possible to solve that validation error?

I have a vague feeling this question was already asked, but cannot get hold of it.

Apologies if that's already been asked, and happy to pull the question if the answer is already available here.

Comment: Have you looked in the Rule Inspector for any validation that may not be obvious?  Also, you have a Correlation ID that you could look for in your SharePoint Logs and see if there is any additional information about what may be happening.

Answer (score 1):

In the fields panel at the bottom click on "Show advanced view" and it will show you all of the fields that exist. The ones that will generate this error should be flagged with a red asterisk.
[image: Show advanced view and example required field]

If you don't see it in the list, you may need to burrow into folders to find it. Also, the fields may be on connections other than Main, so you may need to check the dropdown at the top of the advanced view for other options.